# How to add a delay before starting a Mocha test case?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm writing a unit test for my simple Node.js application using Mocha. The application has a class which connects to a Mongo database, fetch the record, and store the formulated record as a field. Simply, the class looks like this:

```
SampleClass.prototype.record = []; // Store the loaded record
SampleClass.prototype.init = function(db){
    var self = this;
    self.db = mongoose.connection; // Say we already have mongoose object initialized
    self.db.once('open',function(){
        /* schema & model definitions go here */
        var DataModel = mongoose.model( /* foobar */);
        DataModel.findOne(function(err,record){
           /* error handling goes here */ 

           self.record = record; // Here we fetch & store the data
        });
    });
}
```

As seen from the snippet above, once the **SampleClass.init()** is called, the **Sample.record** will not instantly get populated from the database. The data is asynchronously populated once the event 'open' is fired. Thus, there will possibly be a delay after **SampleClass.init()** until the **Sample.record** is populated.

So it comes into a complication when I write a Mocha test like this:

```
var testSampleClass = new SampleClass();

describe('SampleClass init test',function(){
    testSampleClass.init('mydb');
    it('should have 1 record read from mydb',function(){
        assert.equal(testSampleClass.record.length,1);
    });
});
```

The assertion above will always fail because **testSampleClass.record** will not get populated straightaway after **init**. It needs a gap of time to load the data.

How can I delay the test case so it starts a few seconds or more after **testSampleClass.init** is called? Is it also possible to trigger the test case right after an event of my class is fired? Otherwise, this simple case will always fail which I know this is not correct at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `before()` or `beforeEach` hooks (see [here](https://medium.com/@kanyang/hooks-in-mocha-87cb43baa91c) and [here](http://mochajs.org/)). They take `done` callback as argument, which you must call when some asynchronous staff will be completed. So you test should looks like:

```
describe('SampleClass init test',function(){
    before(function(done) {
        testSampleClass.init('mydb', done);
    });
    it('should have 1 record read from mydb',function(){
        assert.equal(testSampleClass.record.length,1);
    });
});
```

And your init method:

```
SampleClass.prototype.record = []; // Store the loaded record
SampleClass.prototype.init = function(db, callback){
    var self = this;
    self.db = mongoose.connection; // Say we already have mongoose object initialized
    self.db.once('open',function(){
        /* schema & model definitions go here */
        var DataModel = mongoose.model( /* foobar */);
        DataModel.findOne(function(err,record){
            /* error handling goes here */

            self.record = record; // Here we fetch & store the data
            callback();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks! This method indeed solves my problem. A very good approach to track that asynchronous call.

Comment: I would like to add that adding a `before` hook outside any test delays the whole suite. Comes in handy when you use global state in your tests like a selenium session for example

Answer (score 16):

@alexpods made a great suggestion. Add following to your test collection so that each test step will wait for 500 msec before running.

```
  beforeEach(function (done) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      done();
    }, 500);
  });
```

or in ES6

```
 beforeEach(done => setTimeout(done, 500));
```

Thanks @Timmerz for the suggestion

Comment: This is the more universal solution, solved my problem of my app open/close way too fast, thanks!

Comment: ES6 version: `beforeEach(done => setTimeout(done, 100));`