# How to set the duration for starting cypress test after code change?

Tags: configuration, cypress

How to set the duration for starting the automatic cypress test run after code change in Visual Studio Code? Could not find anything in the Settings.

Comment: I don't think there is a setting. If a setting existed, it wouldn't be found in Visual Studio, as the Cypress Test Runner is what is watching files, not VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to "debounce" the test re-start after edits are made.

I didn't try this out, but here [How to add a delay before starting a Mocha test case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43218999/16997707) is something to try.

You only want to delay before all tests, so use `before()` instead of `beforeEach()`

```js
before(done => setTimeout(done, 1000))    // 1 second delay before tests restart
```

You can put it at the top of a single spec, or in `/cypress/support/index.js` for all specs.

Comment: That does not work for me. Sorry.